# Paginate pages to receive results from tSQL

Tags: sql, dataexplorer

I try to run a simple query at [sede](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackoverflow/query/1572919?MinimumRep=100000)

Here is the query:

```
SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY u.Displayname DESC) AS row,
    u.Id, u.Reputation
FROM        
    Users u
WHERE       
    u.reputation > ##MinimumRep:int?1000##
    AND row >= ##StartRow:INT?1##
    AND row <= ##EndRow:INT?50000##
ORDER BY    
    row
```

However the error is related to row as it can't recognized. Please could you help me what can I do to fix it?

Comment: @JNevill please could you help with an example?

Comment: I moved my comment to an answer and added the SQL I was explaining. Hope it does the job!

Comment: the `order by` clause has a pagination syntax. check t-sql reference

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to do that `row >=`  and `row <=`  filtering outside of this query (put this query in a subquery and filter in the main query).

Window functions like row_number() OVER are the last steps to run in a sql statement, so by the time that logic is applied, the WHERE clause has long since been executed. Some RDBMS products like Teradata and Snowflake have a QUALIFY clause where you can put those window function filters, but SQL Server 19 which is what is under the hood of dataexplorer does not have that clause, so the subquery is necessary.

Something like the following will likely work:

```
SELECT *
FROM 
    (
      SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY u.Displayname DESC) AS row,
        u.Id, u.Reputation
      FROM        
        Users u
      WHERE       
        u.reputation > ##MinimumRep:int?1000##
    ) dt
WHERE
    row >= ##StartRow:INT?1##
    AND row <= ##EndRow:INT?50000##
ORDER BY  
    row
```

However, as I look at this query, I'm not sure what you are trying to do here. This is identical to:

```
SELECT TOP 50000
  u.Id, 
  u.Reputation
FROM        
  Users u
WHERE       
  u.reputation > ##MinimumRep:int?1000##
ORDER BY DisplayName DESC
```

Which isn't terribly informative.