# Using API to load more than one question ids per call

Tags: r, stackexchange-api

Using a dataframe with question ids from SO:

```
df <- data.frame (qid = c(71663375, 71674701, 71724524))
```

Using the folliwng code it is possible to make 3 api calls to receive info for every question.

However SO app provides the chance to run into 1 call 100 ids. How is it possible to make it?

```
library(stackr)
for (j in 1:nrow(df)) {
  
  questions <- stack_questions(df$qid[j])
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `app` can handles 100 at a time, `split` the `qid` into `list` of vectors with each `list` element holding 100 at a time,

```
lst1 <- split(df$qid, as.integer(gl(nrow(df), 100, nrow(df))))
```

and then use `lapply`

```
library(stackr)
out <- lapply(lst1, stack_questions)
out_dat <- do.call(rbind, out)
```

or `for` loop  to loop over the `list`

```
out <- vector('list', length(lst1))
for(i in seq_along(lst1)) {
   out[[i]] <- stack_questions(lst1[[i]])
}
out_dat <- do.call(rbind, out)
```

-output

```
> out
[[1]]
              tags is_answered view_count accepted_answer_id answer_count score  last_activity_date       creation_date      last_edit_date question_id content_license
1                r        TRUE         32           71724636            1     0 2022-04-03 04:32:10 2022-04-03 04:15:43 2022-04-03 04:23:59    71724524    CC BY-SA 4.0
2                r        TRUE         19           71674900            1     0 2022-03-30 04:38:41 2022-03-30 04:25:06 2022-03-30 04:32:58    71674701    CC BY-SA 4.0
3 sql,dataexplorer       FALSE         27                 NA            1     0 2022-03-29 09:18:20 2022-03-29 08:54:52 2022-03-29 09:00:36    71663375    CC BY-SA 4.0
                                                                                                                          link                                                                           title
1                                            https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71724524/melt-a-dataframe-using-a-list-column                                            Melt a dataframe using a list column
2 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71674701/create-a-new-column-using-detecting-the-domain-of-a-url-from-an-existing-column Create a new column using detecting the domain of a url from an existing column
3                                     https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71663375/paginate-pages-to-receive-results-from-tsql                                     Paginate pages to receive results from tSQL
  owner_account_id owner_reputation owner_user_id owner_user_type                                                                     owner_profile_image owner_display_name
1         24733596                5      18621268      registered https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a/AATXAJwQRtIYRrvKJi1a4AfvTHoE4ht8f_WQ1Qv3jtbr=k-s256            Domin D
2         24733596                5      18621268      registered https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a/AATXAJwQRtIYRrvKJi1a4AfvTHoE4ht8f_WQ1Qv3jtbr=k-s256            Domin D
3         24733596                5      18621268      registered https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a/AATXAJwQRtIYRrvKJi1a4AfvTHoE4ht8f_WQ1Qv3jtbr=k-s256            Domin D
                                        owner_link
1 https://stackoverflow.com/users/18621268/domin-d
2 https://stackoverflow.com/users/18621268/domin-d
3 https://stackoverflow.com/users/18621268/domin-d
```

#### data

```
df <- data.frame (qid = c(71663375, 71674701, 71724524))
```

Comment: How is it possible to make it into the for loop?

Comment: @DominD please see the update

Comment: Thank you, it seems to work. Is is possible to save the out results after the end of the loop into one dataframe?

Comment: @DominD Assuming it gives the same columns, use `out_dat <- do.call(rbind, out)`

Comment: Thank you akrun. If the columns are not the same is it possible to keep specific column names? i.e. out$question_id, out$creation_date?

Comment: @DominD yes, you can use `out_dat[c("question_id", "creation_date")]`

Comment: Is it possible to make it from the list and not from the dataframe?

Comment: @DominD Yes, you can do `out2 <- lapply(out, \(x) x[c("question_id", "creation_date")])`

Comment: thank you I tried it but it gives this error `Error: unexpected input in "out2 <- lapply(out, \"
`

Comment: @DominD i guess you have an older R version, try changing the `\(x)` to `function(x)` i..e `out2 <- lapply(out, function(x) x[c("question_id", "creation_date")])`

Comment: Thank you it works but it provides again a list not a dataframe

Comment: @DominD yes, but I have already given you the code to change it to data.frame i.e. `do.call(rbind, out2)`