# Keep specific rows in a dataframe from a list

Tags: r

From a list from this process:

```
library(stackr)
df <- data.frame (qid = c(71663375, 71674701, 71724524))
lst1 <- split(df$qid, as.integer(gl(nrow(df), 100, nrow(df))))
out <- vector('list', length(lst1))
for(i in seq_along(lst1)) {
   out[[i]] <- stack_questions(lst1[[i]])
}
```

How is it possible to create from out list a new dataframe with the columns tags, creation_date, question_id?

dput of the out list

```
dput(out)
list(structure(list(tags = c("r", "r", "sql,dataexplorer"), is_answered = c(TRUE, 
TRUE, FALSE), view_count = c(33L, 19L, 27L), accepted_answer_id = c(71724636L, 
71674900L, NA), answer_count = c(1L, 1L, 1L), score = c(0L, 0L, 
0L), last_activity_date = structure(c(1648978330, 1648633121, 
1648563500), tzone = "", class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), creation_date = structure(c(1648977343, 
1648632306, 1648562092), tzone = "", class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
)), last_edit_date = structure(c(1648977839, 1648632778, 1648562436
), tzone = "", class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), question_id = c(71724524L, 
71674701L, 71663375L), content_license = c("CC BY-SA 4.0", "CC BY-SA 4.0", 
"CC BY-SA 4.0"), link = c("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71724524/melt-a-dataframe-using-a-list-column", 
"https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71674701/create-a-new-column-using-detecting-the-domain-of-a-url-from-an-existing-column", 
"https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71663375/paginate-pages-to-receive-results-from-tsql"
), title = c("Melt a dataframe using a list column", "Create a new column using detecting the domain of a url from an existing column", 
"Paginate pages to receive results from tSQL"), owner_account_id = c(24733596L, 
24733596L, 24733596L), owner_reputation = c(17L, 17L, 17L), owner_user_id = c(18621268L, 
18621268L, 18621268L), owner_user_type = c("registered", "registered", 
"registered"), owner_profile_image = c("https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a/AATXAJwQRtIYRrvKJi1a4AfvTHoE4ht8f_WQ1Qv3jtbr=k-s256", 
"https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a/AATXAJwQRtIYRrvKJi1a4AfvTHoE4ht8f_WQ1Qv3jtbr=k-s256", 
"https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a/AATXAJwQRtIYRrvKJi1a4AfvTHoE4ht8f_WQ1Qv3jtbr=k-s256"
), owner_display_name = c("Domin D", "Domin D", "Domin D"), owner_link = c("https://stackoverflow.com/users/18621268/domin-d", 
"https://stackoverflow.com/users/18621268/domin-d", "https://stackoverflow.com/users/18621268/domin-d"
)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame", metadata = list(
    has_more = FALSE, quota_max = 10000L, quota_remaining = 1323L)))
```

Comment: Please share a sample of `out` using `dput()`.

Comment: @MartinGal please see the update

Answer (score 1):

```
out[[1]][c('tags', 'creation_date', 'question_id')]

              tags       creation_date question_id
1                r 2022-04-03 05:15:43    71724524
2                r 2022-03-30 05:25:06    71674701
3 sql,dataexplorer 2022-03-29 09:54:52    71663375
```

Or if `out` is a list containing multiple data frames per element:

```
lapply(out, function(x) x[c('tags', 'creation_date', 'question_id')])
```